# Entity Not Found error in symfony2 Form

Tags: forms, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have a symfony2 Form CategoryType with a buildForm:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('language', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'Evr\HomeBundle\Entity\Language',
                    'property' => 'language'
                        )
                )
                ->add('category', 'text', array('label' => 'category.category', 'required' => true));
    }
```

As you can expect, I have two entities Category and Language, of which Category is a child of Language (One language can have many categories, and one category belongs to 1 or 0 language)

**Category**

```
<?php

namespace Evr\HomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Category
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ev_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language",inversedBy="categories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id",referencedColumnName="language_id")
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subcategory", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $subcategories;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->subcategories=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

       /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param integer $language
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setLanguage($language) {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLanguage() {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \string $category
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \string 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

}
```

**Language**

```
<?php

namespace Evr\HomeBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Language
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ev_language")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Language
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=128)
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="direction", type="boolean")
     */
    private $direction;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="language")
     */
    protected $categories;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Country", mappedBy="language")
     */
    protected $countries;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->categories=new ArrayCollection();
        $this->countries=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set language
     *
     * @param string $language
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setLanguage($language)
    {
        $this->language = $language;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get language
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLanguage()
    {
        return $this->language;
    }

    /**
     * Set code
     *
     * @param string $code
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setCode($code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get code
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Set direction
     *
     * @param boolean $direction
     * @return Language
     */
    public function setDirection($direction)
    {
        $this->direction = $direction;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get direction
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getDirection()
    {
        return $this->direction;
    }
}
```

When editing a category, I need to display the current values in a form, so that the user can modify them and save.

Here I have a controller editAction(), whose mission is to display the edition form:

```
   public function editAction($id) { //id of the category to modify

        $category = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EvrHomeBundle:Category')->find($id); //return the category with id

        $categoryForm = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(),$category); //building the form


        return $this->render('EvrAdminBundle:Categories:edit.html.twig', array('categoryForm' => $categoryForm->createView(), 'category' => $category));
    }//render the form
```

Remember that the CategoryType has an element which type : entity, which loads the languages in A select box.

But when trying to populate the form CategoryType with the current data (Category and Language) , Symfony returns an Error : `Entity Not Found`

Symfony doesn't specify in which line the error occures, but I think it's around this line :

```
$categoryForm = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(),$category); //building the form
```

Because when I remove the second argument of `createForm` : `$category`, it displays an empty form (just like an `add category form`

Is there a solution for this issue? And how can I create a form with current data from the database, considering the fact that it contains an entity element.

Thank you

Comment: The explanation in your question helped me identify my problem. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome dude ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `\` in front of entity namespace:

```
'class' => '\Evr\HomeBundle\Entity\Language',
```

Comment: Thank you so much my dear, your answer helped a lot, now it shows `entity was not found anymore`, but it displays a `Class "\Evr\HomeBundle\Entity\Language" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it? ` error.

Just another mapping error, I'm going to try to solve it, +1...

Comment: You mean, removing all the files in this directory? because I used `cache:clear` and the problem persists

Comment: I removed them, but it stills shows the `Class "\Evr\HomeBundle\Entity\Language" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?` error

Comment: You can regenerate entity with code generator, using `php app/console generate:doctrine:entity` in console like in [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html)

Comment: But I already use this entity in other operations "Such as Add, delete, update language"

Comment: And the entity Language I posted in the question is already generated using the command `generate:doctrine:entity` , the only properties I added are `protected categories` and `protected countries`, and the __construct function

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I finally know what's the problem.

When I remove a language, I set the categories in that language to language_id=0 (I don't remove them) in the database (because I may want to use them (and their articles too) when I add the language again.

When I click to update on a category that has language_id=0, symfony2 looks for languages with id=0, and doesn't find it of course.

Comment: So, I removed the `\` you told me to add (because it creates a problem in add category`) and I set language_id of all categories to 1... it works now

Answer (score 4):

If you have a database without referential integrity enforced, then you can delete a record even though another record is pointing to it (they should be linked through a foreign key). Then when you try to grab the record it seem to work but when you want to access attributes of that entity (this is when the real access to the database occurs) it can't find the entity with that record_id and so "Entity not found".

Ex:

```
$user=new User();
$car=$user->getCar();    /*The user had a CAR record assigned with Id = 1 but the record was 
                           deleted.              
                           The record USER still has the id of 1.*/
/*No error up till here*/
$carName=$car->getName();    /*Error occurs because it tries to grab the record with id of 1 
                               which was deleted*/
```