# Entity not found on Symfony 2 form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I generated with the smyfony2 cli tool a CRUD for a entity. Now i want to use the edit function from the CRUD.

First, the code

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Poi entity.
 *
 * @Route("/poi/{id}/edit", name="poi_edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default')->getRepository('Project\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Poi');

    $entity = $em->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Poi entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView()
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Poi entity.
*
* @param Poi $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(Poi $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new PoiType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('poi_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

But i receive a "Entity not found" error. Of course i first of all i thought about the throw of the `NotFoundException`, so i commented it out, but still i get the error.

Then i debugged the code and the entity will be found. It's also existing in the database.

I debugged further and found out that the error is thrown somewhere in the Symfony2 Form stack which generates the form, which is called in the `createEditForm` action.

Do i clearly miss something? What is my error?

My Symfony2 dev log also just says that a `NotFoundException` was thrown, no further information there to be found.

I have another entity with a generated CRUD, but there i build the form in the `createEditForm` by myself because of certain fields that shouldn't be displayed. Do i need to create the form by myself or am i doing something obviously wrong?

Also the PoiType code

```
class PoiType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('situation')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('isPrivate')
            ->add('image')
            ->add('audio')
            ->add('country')
            ->add('category')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Poi'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'project_bundle_projectbundle_poi';
    }
}
```

This is the Error i get:

`CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: "Entity was not found." at /var/www/project-symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/ProxyFactory.php line 177`

Comment: Can you paste your `PoiType` as well?

Comment: Does your entity exist in the database?

Comment: @bartek i already said that in my text that it exist. also this function will be called from the show method of that certain entity, so yeah, it exists ^^

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your entity. Maybe an entity-relation is defined that returns a null value. Do you have a OneToOne relationship - that does not return anything?

Comment: I have a ManyToOne relationship that can return null, but it's set as nullable=true

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a backslash prefix to your `data_class` in your FormType as such:

```
'data_class' => '\Project\Bundle\ProjectBundle\Entity\Poi',
```

Thanks for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413086/entity-not-found-error-in-symfony2-form).

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work. I'll paste the message from the errorlog to my answer